# Content not unpublished

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I am trying to unpublish some content by going to admin/content and then checking the chechbox for those content and then in update options i do a Unpublish selected content but then i get an error: The website encountered an unexpected error...I check the logs i get the error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:
 '' for column 'field_time_to_finish_countdown_timer' at row 1:
 INSERT INTO {field_data_field_time_to_finish} (entity_type, entity_id,
 revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_time_to_finish_countdown_timer)
 VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
 :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
 :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node
 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 135 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 174
 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => challenge [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0
 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => ) in
 field_sql_storage_field_storage_write()
 (line 448 of
 /home/qa/ypwb/public_html/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
```

What is this and how can i rectify that?

Comment: Looks like an issue with the countdown timer module, there's a patch for it: http://drupal.org/node/1871868

Answer (score 2):

It seems you added the field `field_time_to_finish_countdown_timer` to your content type `challenge` after you created some content for this type.

The previously created content do not have any value for this field, causing this error. You may define a default value for this field, such as 0 to get rid of this error.